# Требуется ли в данном случае обособление?

Tags: пунктуация

Особо там не высовывайся, а если случится так, что с людьми(,) сильно превосходящими тебя умом и хитростью(,) столкнешься, то не связывайся с ними.

Вроде ясно, что оборот "сильно превосходящими тебя умом и хитростью" выделяться должен, но сбивает с толку слово "столкнешься" из-за которого часть предложения от "что" до вышеупомянутого "столкнешься" выглядит неделимым куском.

Нужны ли все-таки запятые (,)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Особо там не высовывайся, а если случится так, что с людьми, сильно превосходящими тебя умом и хитростью, столкнешься, то не связывайся с ними*.

Причастный оборот входит в придаточное предложение (то, что Вы назвали неделимым куском), он, конечно, обособляется запятыми с двух сторон, потому что стоит после определяемого слова (с людьми какими?). Сомнений быть не должно, причастный оборот может входить как в самостоятельное предложение, так и в придаточное.